# Kubuntu screensaver won't autostart

Tags: xscreensaver

Am using Ubuntu Lucid + kubuntu-desktop. NVidia works fine. Screensavers set to autostart & worked fine after initial install. Now screensaver attempted to start (brief flash of black only) but since quit doing that.. All screensavers work fine in Test mode. Is there a file entry that controls this?. kde/autostart is empty - should there be an entry here? 
Would the log files show up any relative errors? I am a newbie & the log info is way out of my league! Have not found any relative posts here or other forums. I would appreciate suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure kscreensaver is disabled:
System Settings -> Display and Monitor -> Screen Saver -> Make sure that Start automatically after: is unchecked.

Make sure xscreensaver is installed.  You should have a Screensaver option in settings menu.
Activate the xscreensaver you want to use.

In your user directory ~/.kde/Autostart/ create the file named: xscreensaver.desktop containing the following lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=xscreensaver -no-splash
Name=XScreenSaver
Type=Application
X-KDE-StartupNotify=false
```

Log out and log in again.  xscreensaver should work fine.